# (SQL / PostgreSQL) In a query, how can I translate a field's value into a more human-readable value using another table as a lookup?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have postgresql tables with values like:

```
Table region_data:

region_name | population | region_code
------------+------------+-------------
Region 1    | 120000     | A
Region 2    | 200000     | A
Region 3    | -1         | B
Region 4    | -2         | -1
```

Where some data may not be available (i.e., the -1 and -2 values)

And tables that contain translations for those values:

```
Table data_codes:

code  | meaning
------+-----------------------
-1    | 'Data not available'
-2    | 'Insufficient data'
...
```

and

```
Table region_types:

type  | meaning
------+---------------
A     | Mountain
B     | Grassland
...
```

I want to make a query (actually a view) that returns the human-readable translations provided by the data_code and region_types tables.  For instance, the view would return:

```
Region Name | Population         | Region Type
------------+--------------------+-------------
Region 1    | 120000             | Mountain
Region 2    | 200000             | Mountain
Region 3    | Data Not Available | Grassland
Region 4    | Insufficient Data  | Data Not Available
```

I've tried doing some sub-queries, but they return a lot of duplicate rows where the code doesn't match to anything in the data_code table.

Please help? Thanks!

Comment: Is it still possible to alter the DDL for your database?  If you are able to fully normalize these tables, region_data.region_code should be a foreign key to a region_codes table.  This design would simplify your queries (you would not need a data_codes table, for example, since this information could be merged as part of your region_codes table).

Comment: Another suggestion: write custom functions as stored procedures in your database.  The logic to report the correctly interpreted value for `Population` and `Region Type` can be moved to these functions.  This would greatly simplify the logic of your query.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is no conflict between the data codes and the region codes, then I see two challenges.  One is the data type problem on the `population` column (the value is an integer but the data meaning requires a string).  The other is combining the region codes with the data codes:

```
select rd.region_name,
       (case when population >= 0 cast(population as varchar(255))
             else p.meaning
        end) as population,
       r.meaning
from region_data rd left outer join
     (select type, meaning from region_types
      union all
      select code, meaning from data_codes
     ) r
     on rd.region_code = r.type left outer join
     data_codes p
     on rd.population < 0 and rd.population = p.code;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    r.region_name,
    coalesce(d1.meaning, r.population::text) as population,
    coalesce(d2.meaning, rt.meaning, r.region_code) as region_code
from region_data as r
    left outer join data_codes as d1 on d1.code = r.population
    left outer join data_codes as d2 on d2.code::text = r.region_code
    left outer join region_types as rt on rt.type = r.region_code
order by r.region_name
```

[**=> sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d568e/3)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can post the query. duplicated rows when using joins usually means INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN

Comment: I cannot think of an example where an `inner join` would result in duplicate rows and the corresponding `left join` would not.